# Set focus on a control without bringing the application to the front

Tags: c#

I want to set the focus to a control within an application without giving focus to the whole application.

For example: Click a button which takes a while to load a screen, when the screen is loaded set the focus on one of the controls. In the meantime I have gone to a different application to do something and the focus returns to the previous application.

This happens when I use Keyboard focus or Logical focus.

Is there any way to stop this happening?

Here is the code:

```
    private void SetFocusInternal()
    {
        // Focus the first control we find with the 'PositionCursor' indicator expression
        FrameworkElement controlToFocus = GetFirstRequiresFocusControl();

        // Give focus back to the control which last had it (if any)
        if (controlToFocus == null)
            controlToFocus = GetLastFocusedControl();

        // Just focus the first thing we can find
        if (controlToFocus == null)
            controlToFocus = GetFirstFocusableControl();

        // Using any of the following goes wrong!!
        controlToFocus.Focus();
        Keyboard.Focus(controlToFocus);
        FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(FocusManager.GetFocusScope(this), controlToFocus);
    }
```

Comment: How about this: before setting the focus on your newly shown control, check if your application is active.

Comment: @Rotem - I could do this but this would mean when the user returned to the application the focus would be wrong

Comment: @user402441 You could save the control in an internal field and focus it upon receiving a `WM_APPACTIVATE` message, or something of that kind.